# Instance variables in another class (no single inheritance)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, instance-variables

I want to know how to use an instance variable (class A) in class B. Here is a small code quote that runs normally:

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value
      self.next = None
 
class Stack:
   def __init__(self):
      self.head = Node("head")
      self.size = 0
   def __str__(self):
      cur = self.head.next
      out = ""
      while cur:
         out += str(cur.value) + "->"
         cur = cur.next
      return out[:-3]
```

I wonder how I can use instance variables (`.next` and `.value`) in the class `Stack`. I think instance variables (`.next` and `.value`) can appear and be used only in `Node` class. As I know, we should use single inheritance and `class Stack` should change to `class Stack(Node)`.
Also, I don't understand what `while cur` means. Is it the same as `while True`?

Could you explain this problem for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question_1** : how I can use instance variables (`.next` and `.value`) in the class `Stack`. I think instance variables (`.next` and `.value`) can appear and be used only in `Node` class. As I know, we should use single inheritance and `class Stack` should change to `class Stack(Node)`?

**Answer_1** : in `def ___init__` we create variable of `Node` then we can use `.next` and `.value` of `self.head` because this variable is instance of `Node class`.

**Question_2** : Also, I don't understand what `while cur` means. Is it the same as `while True`?

**Answer_2** : for first `Node` we set `.next = None` then when we have multiple nodes we run on nodes until get `Node.next == None` then `None` assign to `cur` and we exit from `while-loop` when `cur` will be `None`.

Comment: You are welcome. The core of your answer is correct but you should pay more attention to case (Python is case-sensitive).

Comment: @Wolf, I'll always remember your advice.

Comment: If you look into the [revision history of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68813954/revisions), you'll see that we all make these mistakes from time to time, despite all our good intentions!  Fortunately, running a script in Python helps.

Comment: @user1740577 In question 2, does `while cur` mean `while cur is not None`?

Comment: @jacobdavis, yes and when `whil cur is None` we exit from `while-loop`

Comment: @user1740577 With regard to `self.head = Node("head")`, is it the same as `self.head = Node()` or `self.head = Node(None)`? We use String `'head'` in the `class Node`, so we have an object here?

Comment: @jacobdavis, `Node("head")` or `Node()` or `Node(None)` you pass "head" , "" , None for `self.value` of instance of `Node class`. you can send any but better if you send string in all of your programs send a string is better you keep routine in all your programs.

Comment: @user1740577 Why we use next pointer `self.next` here? Can we remove it?

Comment: @jacobdavis, no you can not remove it, for the first node we set it `None` but for other Nodes, we set this to a reference other Nodes, do you know about `Linked List` in this code we create a `stack` with `Linked List`, see these linkes maybe help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-in-python/

Comment: @user1740577 Thank you very much. I  know about `Linked list` in my current book.